# Laravel Vue & Vuex by Webpack

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2, vuex

Laravel give you app.js for Vue.js out of the box.
So when I try to create component everything is ok.

```
//app.js file

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

But how to add Vuex???
I have tried import modules inside app.js and bootstrap.js  and every time got error - like Vue not defined or Vuex not defined.
How to do it right? I use all out of box, Webpack for compiling app.js i public folder.

Comment: Did you install the [VueX package](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/installation.html) ?

Comment: Yes sure.It all happen, because i tried to use ES6 import statement but in laravel all in ES5.. so i little bit messed..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
window.Vuex = require('vuex');
```

to bootstrap.js